# Run multiple Outlook Macros

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I found a macro to automatically download attachments from certain emails.  I now want to run a batch file after the file is downloaded.  I was wondering how to make a both modules run?  Do they need to be on the same module?

Here is my code:

Module Name - Download

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\username\Documents\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Module Name - RunBat

```
Sub CallOtherProgram()
Shell "C:\Users\username\Desktop\BatchFile.bat", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Is there anyways I can make these run one after the other?  I am very new to scripting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a call to `CallOtherProgram` in your original procedure:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\username\Documents\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next

    CallOtherProgram

End Sub
```

Comment: Should they still be separate modules then?  Or do I put the CallOtherProgram with the Shell command on the next line?

Comment: You can go either way. Separate modules, with the first calling the second as per the answer, or copy the code from the second module into the first.  It depends on what seems neatest to you.

Comment: [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) says you keep concerns isolated, then if you ever need to `CallOtherProgram` anywhere else, you already have a procedure you can call.